# What are the advantages and disadvantages of Protractor and Canopy-web-testing?

Tags: protractor, canopy-web-testing

I am looking for the best automation tool to automate my web application. So, can someone please tell me the advantages and disadvantages of above two tools?

Comment: What kind of tests? What's your experience level in both languages?

Comment: Could you please more details about the web application like  for what purpose it is used and what technology is used to build it . Also what kind of testing you want to perform (whether it's a unit test or regression test)

Comment: @lloyd - I am new to both the languages

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath - I am looking for the regression testing and the application is based on AngularJS framework.

Comment: If its Angular app then why not use Protractor?  It was made by the Angular team for testing.  Protractor is backed by Google, updated frequently, and has a lot of documentation.  Canopy offers much less in comparison